# Retries with Cypress Cucumber

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Could you advice how to `retry` Scenario in Cypress Cucumber if it fails? If I use for ex. `retries:2` in cypress.json, and two test scenarios, when the first scenario fails it retries only the second scenario.

Comment: Did you find some solution? The Cypress documentation says to use retries in cypress.json, but this seems to be buggy, or directly to put retries in each test case. However it is for pure cypress, not cucumber preprocessor. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries#Configure-Test-Retries

Comment: I had similar challenges with retries using Cypress and Cucumber Preprocessor. Without own custom retry solution this unfortunately does not work. I posted my experience and approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70536640/6135684

Answer (score 3):

cypress-cucumber-preprocessor doesn't have that feature till now. However, you can try [Cytorus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cytorus) in this case. This is the example to make a scenario retriable.

```
#> retries: 2
Scenario: This is a scenario
    Given I access a site on slow network
    Then it opens
```

Ref: [cytorus docs](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/cytorus/blob/master/docs/10.Miscellaneous.md)

Answer (score 0):

This is now allowed in the latest @Badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor using a standard tag for a Scenario: @retries(5)

https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/commit/760342adcefee8deae07f37e637cab4b27045464#diff-eb46c03cad007b07552d9f839954807d38a5a9227c3cd156f55a076afee58250R18